# how to find all the restaurants near a particular city in HERE API

Tags: web-services, here-api

I'm working on a project that the user selects a city and i have to display all the restaurants in the city. I got app_id and app_code from HERE API but don't know how to use this.. i finished the frond end using bootstrap.

Comment: You need to give it ago before you start asking for help, show what you have tried so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Places API https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/overview.html

For example, try this link (don't forget to put your credentials in it):

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?in=52.5303581%2C13.3848515%3Br%3D10000&cat=eat-drink&size=10000&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

In this example, you will search for any type of food places around Berlin in 10km radius.